# i'm trying to modify this css code. how will i prevent it from shrinking whenever i click on it

Tags: html, css, animation

[This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKvzMb) is what I'm trying to modify. 
I tried

```
&:active {
flex:7;}
```

but when I released the left click button it shrank back to its original width.

I was more trying to achieve something like this

```
    <h1>Gallery</h1>

      <div class="gallery-wrap">
      <div class="item item-1"></div>
      <div class="item item-2"></div>
      <div class="item item-3"></div>
      <div class="item item-4"></div>
      <div class="item item-5"></div>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2n3f6em/11/

but it requires javascript which i am not good at.

Comment: It's easiest for people reading your question if you include code as a code snippet instead of a link to an outside webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using jQuery to change toggle a `.active` class on your `.item`

```js
jQuery('.item').click(function(){
   //check if clicked in an opened item | this closes an opened item
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
     jQuery(this).removeClass('active'); return;
   }
   jQuery('.item').each(function(){ //remove .active from all 
    jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
   })
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggle .active from current
});
```

```css
.panel {
   height: 100vh;
}
.gallery-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  transition: flex 0.3s ease;
}
.item.active {
  flex: 7;
}

.panel.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.panel.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.panel.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Gallery</h1>

      <div class="gallery-wrap">
      <div class="item item-1 panel red"></div>
      <div class="item item-2 panel blue"></div>
      <div class="item item-3 panel green"></div>
      <div class="item item-4 panel red"></div>
      <div class="item item-5 panel blue"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: i tried active. still when i release the click button it shrink back to its original size. i want it to remain at 60% width when clicked until i click another bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using focus

```
#item:focus {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Try playing around with this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp